# click event Highchart legends

Tags: php, highcharts, yii, yii2

i have following series on high chart when i click on legends it will appear a alert message. i have given `type : 'spline'` for series name **'spend'** when i give this alert window is not appearing. can anyone help

> when i remove type: 'spline' from inside of series it will appear
>   alert message. and i have give given common type: 'line' as below

```
$('#conv').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
            type: 'line',
        },
```

**series are below**

```
series: [{
                name: 'Spend',
                type : 'spline',
                marker: {symbol: 'circle',
                        fillColor: '#5cabf5',                     
                },
               // type: 'column',

                yAxis: 1,
                color: '#5cabf5',
                data: [<?php echo $spend;?>],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' $'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Total Conversions',

                marker: {symbol: 'circle',
                        fillColor: '#e65100',                     
                },
                color: '#e65100',
                data: [<?php echo $total;?>],
                }*/
            }]
```

alert event is given below

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {

                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                            var series = this.chart.series;
                             var seriesIndex = this.index;
                            var thisSeries=this.name;
                            var invisib=[];
                            invisib.push(thisSeries);

                             var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';

                            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++){
                                    if(series[i].visible==false){
                                        if(!(thisSeries in invisib))
                                        {
                                        invisib.push(series[i].name);
                                    }
                                    }

                            }
                            alert(invisib);
                        //saveintocookie(invisib);

                    }
                },
            showInLegend: true
        }
        }
```

[Click the link to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i057U.png)

Comment: The problem is you've set the series type as a spline but your event listener is only set to listen on line series. If you want to catch all charts then put the event under `plotOptions: { series: { events: ...`

Comment: Solution is fine